# Useful file output from reading a file (ruby/rails environment)

Tags: ruby, file

I have a model connected to a log, so I'm beginning to build ways to use that info with the model and pass it around elsewhere.

this method:

```
  def read_log
    counter = 1 
    f = File.open(self.log_file_path, 'r')
    while (line = f.gets)
      puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
      counter = counter + 1
    end
  end
```

works, and dumps the log to the command line but ends with nil, so it reads it out to stdout but when calling that I get nothing. How can I read the contents into a more useful format? I need to read this into a controller variable for a template within rails on a webpage. It is basic, but something I haven't done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contents = f.read
```

Now `contents` contains... the contents. Not sure what "useful" means in your context, but you can do things like split on newline to get each line.

You can also create an enumerator via `f.lines`, whether or not that's more useful, not sure.

Comment: This is what I did minutes after submitting this question.